# Resetting socket connection

Tags: c++, sockets

My application connects as a client across an ethernet to a server process.

As the server is well known and will not change, UDP and TCP are both setup using

```
socket(); 
setsockopt(SO_REUSEADDR);
bind(); 
connect();
```

The connection protocol includes heartbeats sent both ways.

When I detect an error with the connection e.g. hearbeat timeout, I need to reset the connection.

Is it sufficient just to connect() to the NULL address and then re-connect() after a short pause, or should I close the socket and then reinitialise from scratch?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to [`close(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/close.2.html) the socket and re-do everything again. Why do you [`bind(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/bind.2.html) on the client?

Comment: I bind() so that the source port and address is specified - the server only accepts connections from known ports and addresses.

Answer (score 2):

After a socket error you have to discard the one in hand and restart the setup with a new socket.

[Winsock documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms737625%28VS.85%29.aspx), for example:

> When a connection between sockets is
>   broken, the sockets should be
>   discarded and recreated. When a
>   problem develops on a connected
>   socket, the application must discard
>   and recreate the needed sockets in
>   order to return to a stable point.